# Spark Standalone DROP TABLE does not delete HDFS files

Tags: apache-spark

Using Apache Spark version 1.6.2. When we want to debug locally against data in our remote cluster we are currently running spark standalone on our HDFS cluster and connecting to the remote cluster with the following code:

```
sparkConf.setMaster("spark://IPADDRESS:7077").set("spark.executor.memory", "4G")
sparkConf.setJars(Array(...))
System.setProperty("hive.metastore.uris","thrift://metastore:9083")
```

This works well with one exception. For some reason when we drop a table when remotely attached it doesn't delete the tables warehouse files on HDFS (/apps/warehouse/database.db/table). However, if we run the same job directly in yarn cluster rather than spark standalone mode it does delete the table's HDFS files. I didn't see any obvious permission errors or anything like that in the spark logs.

Is there a way to get the same behavior out of spark standalone?